# Que me devuelva el ID de un usuario cuando se cumple conidicion de cantidad de eventos

Tags: mysql, sql

Se que el título es medio vago, asique mejor lo explico por acá. Primero que nada quiero aclarar que esto creo que es un poco difícil, espero que no les haga perder mucho el tiempo je.

Hagamos de cuenta que tengo mi siguiente tabla, llamada T1:

| ID | VIVIENDA | COLOR | FECHA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2542 | Casa | Roja | 2022-01-01 |
| 53 | Dpto | Azul | 2022-02-01 |
| 2542 | Casa | Roja | 2022-03-01 |
| etc | etc | etc | etc |

En esta tabla tengo datos de usuarios (ID) que compraron un tipo de vivienda (Casa, Departamento, Ph, etc) en un determinado color. Están ordenados por cuándo se compro esa vivienda

¿Qué estoy tratando de hacer?

Estoy tratando de realizar una query donde me traiga todos  los usuarios cuyas últimas 3 compras (que serían en el caso del título, los eventos), en los últimos meses, hayan sido una *casa* *roja*

Voy hacer honesto, se me complicó bastante jajaja. Voy a poner lo último que estuve haciendo hasta recién y luego explicar como lo estaba pensando:

```
set a=0
set b=3
select ID from T1 
where (iff ((select top 1 COLOR from T1 order by ID)='Roja', $a=$a+1, NULL))=$b
```

Lo que estaba intentando acá era que, cuando el último registro sea *Roja*, a *a* se le sumará 1 entonces cuando sea =3, va ser igual a *b*  me tendría que devolver el ID.
Obviamente FALTA muchas cosas, si hago esto me devolverá una query vacía: intenté creando un loop con el *WHILE* pero todos los intentos fueron erróneos, ejemplo:

```
codigo...
while ( (select max (ID)) = (select max (ID)-1)) do
mas o menos lo de arriba
```

Acá intenté es, ordenar los ID y luego si el último ID era el mismo que el que le seguía Y tenía el evento COLOR='Roja', sumarmle +1 a *a*  (es más o menos lo que hice arriba, sin el while).

Pondría todo lo que hice pero creo que sería para confusión (imaginense que ni siquiera intenté filtrarlo por fecha jaja), ya que se que todo lo que hice me tiró error o me devolvia todo vacío, simplemente escribí eso para que vean mi "linea de pensamiento" y bueno, tal vez sea de ayuda.

Si a alguien se le ocurre como puedo continuar o si se les ocurre alguna otra forma de hacer esta consulta se los agradecería (no estoy tratandola de hacer eficiente ni nada por el estilo, simplemente que aunque me tarde 20 minutos me devuelva lo que quiero jaja).
Sé que podría hacer una bajada y luego hacer esto en Excel pero bueno, soy terco y estoy practicando je.

Cualquier cosa, estoy usando Snowflake o MySql

Comment: Dos preguntas ¿últimos meses te refieres a qué intervalo, 3 meses, 4? Y segundo ¿puedes pasar algún script para llenar la tabla?

Comment: ¿ **todas** las tres últimas compras del mismo comprador deben ser una casa roja?  ¿o alguna de las últimas tres?

Comment: @lsanchezo en cualquier intervalo de tiempo, igual eso sería lo último que me gustaría hacer, ya creo que sería lo mas fácil una vez resuelto lo otro

Comment: @masterguru Nono, solo las últimas tres últimas compras deben de ser una casa roja

Comment: Intente algo como [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a852f79b29fb50e0c4b0e10c7c0a74dc).